# jQuery sortable resize on remove

Tags: jquery

Quite a simple question ive got a few sortable unordered lists

1. with images that resized to the div by absolute and the li which class `.image_block` which has width/height and float at 100px so something like this

`<ul>

<li class='.image_block'><img src="pic.png"</li>

<li class='.image_block'><img src="pic1.png"</li>

<li class='.image_block'><img src="pic2.png"</li>

<ul>`

1. And a few other seperate lists which have different li heights and widths

so what i want to acheive is as soon as i drag a picture from one of the random width/height it adds `.image_block`

And at the moment i have this which is not working

```
    $(".dragable_column").sortable({opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move',connectWith: ['.dragable_column','.dragable_userimages'],

    receive: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass(".image_block");
 },

    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass(".image_block");
    }
```

});

```
$(".dragable_userimages").sortable({opacity: 0.8,axis: 'x', cursor: 'move',connectWith: ['.dragable_column'],
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass(".image_block");
 }
```

});

Any help would be greatly aprriciated

Answer (score 1):

The `.` character should not be part of the class name.  Indeed, it is an illegal character in class names.  You are confusing CSS/jQuery selectors with element classes.  The selector `.image_block` is the same as saying "the element with the class `image_block`", i.e. without the `.`.

Try changing your code to use the class `image_block` instead.

Also, your HTML is wonky.  Apart from anything else, you need to close your `img` tags and use `</ul>` to close your list, not `<ul>`.

Comment: @Riskeh If this has answered your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick to the side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay well i figured out to do it knew it was simple just had to change the width and height of the `ui.helper` object with so heres how i done it

```
$(".dragable_column").sortable({opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move',connectWith: ['.dragable_column','.dragable_userimages'],

    receive: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).removeClass("image_block");
        var height = $(this).attr("row_height");
        $(ui.item).attr("style","height:"+height+";");


    },

    start: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).width(100).height(100);

    } 
});

$(".dragable_userimages").sortable({opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move',connectWith: ['.dragable_column'],
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).attr("style","");
        $(ui.item).addClass("image_block");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that works perfectly:

```
$("ul.sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: "highlight",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // Resize elements
        $(this).sortable('refreshPositions'); 
    }
});
```

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/reducing-the-size-of-elements-before-sorting-them-using-sortable